# The Riemann-Stieltjes Integral Counterexample Prove

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, there exist a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that
>   $$\int_a^b f(x)\, dt = f(c)\cdot(b-a).$$

Now, give an example to show that for an arbitrary increasing function on $[a,b]$, the above statement may fail.

I'm confusion about the question. since our textbook have proven that: $\int_a^b f\, dg = f(c)\cdot(g(b)-g(a))$, but now the question ask us to give an counterexample.

Comment: The textbook proves the equation is true for _continuous_ functions.  The exercise says _arbitrary_.  So that should give you a hint as to what kind of function you need.

Comment: I got, so could I set a increasing piece function to show it's not true.

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: It is not true for monotone functions as monotone functions may not have intermediate value property...

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = \begin{cases}0 \hspace{1em} x \in (0,\frac{1}{2}] \\ 1 \hspace{1em} x \in (\frac{1}{2},1)\end{cases}$

Then $f$ is increasing and $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}$ but $f(c) = 0$ or $1$ for any $c \in (0,1)$, so $f(c) \cdot (1-0) = f(c) \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=x$ if $x<1$ and $f(x)=x+3$ if $x\geq 1$

we have $$\int_0^2 f(x) \, dx=5$$ and $b-a=2$ it should exist  $c\in[0,2]$ such that $f(c)=2.5$ but this doesn't happen.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it.